# OpenCL strange behavior

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Good day,

I think I've tried everything to figure out where the problem is but I couldn't. I have the following code for a host:

```
cl_mem cl_distances = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 2 * sizeof(cl_uint), NULL, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &cl_distances);

cl_event event;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_workers, &local_workers, 0, NULL, &event);

clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
```

And for a device:

```
__kernel void walk(__global uint *distance_results)
{
    uint global_size = get_global_size(0);
    uint local_size = get_local_size(0);

    uint global_id = get_global_id(0);
    uint group_id = get_group_id(0);
    uint local_id = get_local_id(0);

    for (uint step = 0; step < 500; step++) {
        if (local_id == 0) {
            distance_results[group_id] = 0;
        }

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        for (uint n = global_id; n < 1000; n += global_size) {
            if (local_id == 0) {
                atomic_add(&distance_results[group_id], 1);
            }
        }

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

        if (global_id == 0) {
            for (uint i = 0; i < (global_size / local_size); i++) {
                printf("step: %d; group: %d; data: %d\n", step, i, distance_results[i]);
            }
        }

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
}
```

So at each "step" I just add one 1 to distance[group_id] 1000 times from each group. And then I just read the result from thread with global_id == 1.
At each step I should have the following text:

> step: 59; group: 0; data: 500 
>   step: 59; group: 1; data: 500

But actually there are a lot of strings with wrong data:

> step: 4; group: 0; data: 500
>   step: 4; group: 1; data: 210
>   step: 5; group: 0; data: 500
>  
>   step: 5; group: 1; data: 214

If I set global_workers to 1 and local_workers to 1 then everything is okay. But if I set global_workers to 2 and local_workers to 1 then I have this strange behavior.

Do you have any ideas why this can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here, but I think the core problem comes from a very common misunderstanding with OpenCL.  This call:

```
barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

This is not a global barrier.  It is a local barrier with a global memory fence.  In other words, it still only synchronizes between work items in a single work group, not between work items in other work groups.

The loop in the code that prints the results will only have correct values for work group 0, since it is only run in work group 0.  If you really want this code to work, the loop that prints the results would have to be in a separate NDRange, with proper synchronization between the NDRanges.

The memory fence just controls which types of memory writes will be committed to memory.  And in this case, you want global fences for both, since you are trying to fence global memory writes, not local memory writes.